# How to add multiple columns from multiple dataframes while keeping an identifying column constant in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, addition

I have several dataframes
`a, b, c, d, e` with same column names `person_id, place_x, place_y, place_z`

How can I sum all the values of the different dataframes for only the `place_x place_y place_z`columns?

A final dataframe, something like this :

```
person_id     place_x       

001           a[place_x] +... e[place_x]
```

I have tried

```
a=a.set_index('person_id')
b=b.set_index('person_id')
df_sum = a.add(b, fill_value=0)
c=set_index('person_id') 
df_sum = df_sum.add(c,fill_value=0)
// and so on until e
```

The values in each column gets added up correctly. But then so does the person_id, which, for example, becomes `001001` instead of just `001` 
How can I stop this from happening?

Also, is there a way to streamline this, so that I can add all that is required in one sentence altogether? Instead of multiple additions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
dfs = [a,b,c,d,e]
df = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('person_id', as_index=False).sum()
```